# (Non-interactive/Line-oriented) command line email inbox viewer tool, configurable for any imap?

Tags: imap, inbox, mutt, command-line-interface

After using Taskwarrior to manage my todo list from the command line, I'd like to do something similar with email. A program that behaves like the below. Am I imagining something that doesn't exist, or can existing tools do this? I don't believe pine or mutt have any non-interactive invocation modes. They take you to their own shells, which I don't want. I want to be able to pipe the output into another unix command.

$ mail_program list inbox

From    Subject   Received

----    -------   ----

mom     re: Hi    2011-09-17

$ mail_program list inbox | grep mom

mom     re: Hi    2011-09-17

$

Answer (score 0):

you have the `mail` or even `mailx` program. That are interactive, but if you just want to print out your mails you can run

```
$ mail -p

$ mailx -r
```